# С клавиатуры вводятся n целых чисел. Вычислить сумму отрицательных чисел, кратных трем

Tags: python, for

```
n = int(input('Введите число'))
v = [0] * n
s = 0
for i in range(n):
    v[i] = int(input(''))
print(v)
i = 0
while i < 0:
    if(v[i] % 3 == 0):
        s = s + v[i]
    i = i + 1
print("сумма: ", sum(v))
```

написал код, но сумму выводит всех чисел, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы суммировалось, как сказано в задании?

Comment: ifv[i] % 3 == 0 and v[i]<0:

Comment: нужно проверять не только кратность на три, но и отрицательное ли число

Comment: Меня больше смущает `while i < 0`

Answer (score 3):

```
print(sum(e for e in [int(input()) for i in range(int(input('Введите число: ')))] if e % 3 == 0 and e < 0))
```